# How can I burn a .mkv larger than 5GB on multiple DVD's without losing any quality?

Tags: backup, dvd, dvd-burning

How can I burn a .mkv larger than 5GB on multiple DVD's without losing any quality?
I don't want to zip them and then unzip them when I want to play the video. I just want it to get split into parts without any loss in quality so that I can play it just by inserting the DVD into the DVD drive of my computer and letting it play. And when the content comes to an end on that DVD, I'll just eject it and insert the next DVD into the drive and keep playing the video.

P.S. I use Ashampoo Burning Studio 14 for burning files.

Answer (score 0):

Download Free Studio from DVD Video Soft and use the video clipping tool. I forget it's name, but it allows you to trim, or split a video file. It doesn't re-encode so their is NO data loss at all, and it supports a decent number of video codecs. Then burn the individual new clips to dvds using whatever program u normally do.

It's worth noting that when you convert video files to dvd video format to create a DVD (with ANY program) the process is typically not lossless because dvd video has standardized bitrates that won't be high enough unless the source is terribly low quality. It's no different than when people convert music files between lossy formats like mp3 to wma.

Comment: I don't want to play the DVD's on DVD players, I'll play them on my PC. So, don't need to convert them to DVD files. I like the Video clipper idea you suggested. Will try that out.